# C++ How to handle this extra task in client server model?

Tags: c++, client-server

I have a `server.cpp` running in background

`client.cpp` will connect to server and perform its task.

I code the server to listen for connection, `while(1)`, and fork a process for client.

But I have a reminder feature which needs to email customer on a certain time. How do I run that feature together in this server, client cpp file?  Should it be run in server or in client file, and in what way?  I have tried to fork() at client.cpp but the issue is it cause my client to not work well.

Where should I add this code, and how do i make it work while performing listening to connection at `server.cpp`?

Comment: Where is the information needed to generate the reminders stored? Is it in a database?

Comment: How does the server main loop look like? What are you using to listen for clients? Are you using some library, `select()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In server code:

```
while(1) {
  check for update time and 
        fork updater if needed
  listen for clients
  fork client
}
```

Alternatively, the server can create a seperate thread with this code:

```
while (1) {
   sleep for some time
   update customers
}
```